# What´s the most suitable software and way to do this kind of CALENDARS?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, software-recommendation, adobe-fireworks, template-design, data-visualisation

I like 2 kinds of annual calendar.

ONE is this 
[image]
( [origianl in PDF](http://portal.uned.es/pls/portal/docs/PAGE/UNED_MAIN/SERVICIOSGENERALES/CALENDARIO/CALENDARIO%202015-16%20FORMATO%20BOLSILLO.PDF) )

ANOTHER(numer two) is this 
[image]
( [origianl in PDF](http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/images/151734-exam-dates-2015.pdf) )

---

I usually use Fireworks CS6 (and may be than in a few months I´m going to use Illustrator), but thw question is what do you think is the most suitable software to do this kind of calendars, and little explication of how to making one.
A grid?
Aligning weeks after aligning columns of the days(numbers)?
Is a special way to do this kind of calendar?

Thank you very much.
Best Regards.

Comment: That first one is almost identical to a template that's available on Google docs version of excel, 'sheets'. You could find it fairly easily, change the colours and add a logo. Would be pretty quick and easy. Can also save to PDF without the grid lines and really easily update later.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer.

In no particular order: Ilustrator, Corel Draw, Indesign, Scribus.

Probably some other like PagePlus.

---

Regarding how... Look for specific "table" tools on each program.

I cheat a bit and prepare an initial file on excell, and from there I experiment how to export the data to my program, but probably this question is too board, becouse you first need to choose a program.

A simple but basic recomendation would be:

Work in layers!

[image]

If you need a style to a part of the information, day number. Put that in one layer.

Changing data like holidays, put them in another layer.

Borders, in another.

This way you can modify the style of each without affecting the other.

Also, prepare some styles for texts, do not make them one by one.